# openSUSE installation on a micro-SD-card

Tags: boot, installation, bios, sd-card, opensuse

Today I tried to install openSUSE Leap 42.1 on a micro-SD-card. I used a USB stick as installation medium. So far everything has gone well. The installation finished without any problems.

Then I went to the BIOS to select the card as Boot Option #1. But I couldn't find the card there!

I've tested the reader and the card, and they are both working.  The card has three partitions:

[image: screenshot]

What do I have to change in order to make the micro-SD-card appear in the BIOS?

Comment: First step is to verify that the reader and the card are working.  Try a different card in the reader to see if it's recognized.  Try the problem card in another reader to see if it's recognized.

Comment: @fixer1234 I forgot to mention that I am using a MICRO SD-card. Tried two card readers, one with a micro-SD to SD adapter and one micro-SD card reader. Everything works fine, there are three patitions on the SD-card ([link](http://pasteboard.co/9v9pBkHMa.png)). But still no entry in the BIOS :-(

Comment: From user [Tomas Rojo](http://superuser.com/users/631345/tomas-rojo): Begin by consulting documentation for your computer to confirm that booting from the SD card slot is supported. Even if that was not the case at the time it was manufactured, there is a chance that booting from SD card was enabled by subsequent firmware updates. Check the website of the computer manufacturer to ensure that your system is running with the latest version of BIOS firmware.